# How to create a macro in Notepad++ that will save a file as a different name?

Tags: notepad++, macros, file-management, export, save-as

In Notepad++, how can you create a macro that will save the current file with a different name?

When I use the macro recorder in Notepad++, it doesn't seem to record any `Save` operation.

Ideally, I would like to have Notepad++ save the current file in the same location as it was opened, but delete the last 9 characters in the filename.  For example, if the current file is:

`c:\foo\bar123456789.c`

I would like to have a Notepad++ macro save it as:

`c:\foo\bar.c`

(overwriting any file with that name)

That's the ideal goal, but even if I can just get a Notepad++ macro to come close to that, it will be an improvement over manually performing that operation.

Answer (score 1):

You can run a python script within the PythonScript plugin.

If it is not yet installed, follow this [guide](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/community/topic/17256/guide-how-to-install-the-pythonscript-plugin-on-notepad-7-6-3-7-6-4-and-above)

Create a script (Plugins >> PythonScript >> New Script)

Copy this code and save the file (for example `replace.py`):

```python
import re

# Define the new filename
newFilename = notepad.getCurrentFilename()

# remove up to 9 characters before extension
newFilename = re.sub(r'.{1,9}(?=\.\w+$)', '', newFilename)

# Save current file with new name
notepad.saveAs(newFilename);
```

- Open the file you want to change
- Run the script (Plugins >> PythonScript >> Scripts >> replace)
- Done

**Regex explanation:**

```
.{1,9}          # 1 upto 9 any characters
(?=             # positive lookahead, make sure we have after (without capturing)
    \.              # a dot
    \w+             # 1 or more word characters
  $               # end of string
)               # end lookahead
```

If there is **always** 9 char to remove, use `.{9}` instead of `.{1,9}`

Comment: Thank you so much.  That looks great.  Upvoted.  It's easy to assign the script to a shortcut key combination, but can it be run as *part* of a macro (likely the last command in the macro)?

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket: You're welcome, glad it helps. I haven't try to run it in a macro, but I'm sure this can be done.